# movie.map is not an function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to add some interface to the API and encounter an error which states that movies.map is not an function.

I've check for spelling issues nothing particular found.

````
```
import React from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

import { MovieCard } from '../movie-card/movie-card';
import { MovieView } from '../movie-view/movie-view';

export class MainView extends React.Component {

  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
      movies: null,
      selectedMovie: null
    };
  }

  // One of the "hooks" available in a React Component
  componentDidMount() {
    axios.get('<https://myflixapi123.herokuapp.com/movies>')
      .then(response => {
        // Assign the result to the state
        this.setState({
          movies: response.data
        });
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }

  onMovieClick(movie) {
    this.setState({
      selectedMovie: movie
    });
  }

  render() {
    const { movies, selectedMovie } = this.state;

    // Before the movies have been loaded
    if (!movies) return  <div className="main-view" />;

    return (
      <div className="main-view">
      {selectedMovie
        ? <MovieView movie={selectedMovie}/>
        : movies.map(movie => (
          <MovieCard key={movie._id} movie={movie} onClick={movie => this.onMovieClick(movie)}/>
        ))
      }
      </div>
    );
}
}
```
````

It should load reactdom but I receive error message in developer tools:

```
Uncaught TypeError: movies.map is not a function
    at MainView.render (main-view.jsx:48)
    at finishClassComponent (react-dom.development.js:14741)
    at updateClassComponent (react-dom.development.js:14696)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:15644)
    at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:19312)
    at workLoop (react-dom.development.js:19352)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:149)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:199)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:256)
    at replayUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:18578)
react-dom.development.js:17117 The above error occurred in the <MainView> component:
    in MainView (created by MyFlixApplication)
    in MyFlixApplication

Consider adding an error boundary to your tree to customize error handling behavior.
 boundaries.
logCapturedError @ react-dom.development.js:17117
main-view.jsx:28 TypeError: movies.map is not a function
    at MainView.render (main-view.jsx:48)
    at finishClassComponent (react-dom.development.js:14741)
    at updateClassComponent (react-dom.development.js:14696)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:15644)
    at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:19312)
    at workLoop (react-dom.development.js:19352)
    at renderRoot (react-dom.development.js:19435)
    at performWorkOnRoot (react-dom.development.js:20342)
    at performWork (react-dom.development.js:20254)
    at performSyncWork (react-dom.development.js:20228)
```

If you see any solutions to that issue please let me know, Thank You!

Comment: `.map()` is for arrays only

Comment: check if `response.data` is an array

Comment: Would you post the schema or json result of `response.data`? And also this looks like a typo `axios.get('<https://myflixapi123.herokuapp.com/movies>')` where you have angle brackets for the URL

Comment: The response.data should be an array of objects in JSON i've written them in mongoDB the shema is:var movieSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  Title : {type: String, required: true},
  Description : {type: String, required: true},
  Genre : {
    Name : String,
    Description : String
  },
  Director : {
    Name : String,
    Bio : String
  },
  ImagePath : String,
  Featured : Boolean
});

Comment: I've think that removing that brackets resolve problem but now I've to worry about cors policy Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://myflixapi123.herokuapp.com/movies' from origin 'http://localhost:1234' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Thats odd because I did not blocked any   Thanks for pointing out that url it's a progress now.

Comment: Here is my cors policy: var allowedOrigins = ['*'];

// Cross - Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) module:
app.use(cors({
  origin: function(origin, callback){
    if(!origin) return callback(null, true);
    if(allowedOrigins.indexOf(origin) === -1){
      var message = 'The CORS policy for this application dosent allow access from origin: ' + origin;
      return callback(new Error(message ), false);
    }
    return callback(null, true);
  }
}));

Answer (score 0):

Initialize `movies` state as an empty array (`movies: []`) instead of `null`. That way your `setState()` code in `componentDidMount()` will change it to `response.data`.

Hope this helps!